# kinect v2 as webcam

Tags: webcam, kinect-v2

The following simple python code is for detecting and tracking the object based on color by using webcam.

My question is how can use the same code but by using Kinect v2 (NOT webcam).

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, linux

Any one can help with this, and tell me how to use Kinect v2 as webcam in linux ???

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('Original',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('Detect-Blue',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution here is one. For Linux, there is an open source library called, "[libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2)" which I have been using to grab images from Kinect2. Once you are done with the installation part then you could play with the program "[Protonect.cpp](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/examples/Protonect.cpp)" as per you needs. In the same program you could added your code after the "while" loop at line#349. It will do the job. And of course, you have to add the OpenCV header files as you are using cv2 functionalities.

By the way, I have installed the library on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia Jetson TK1 and both are working fine. In my work, I used it only to save the images and create 3D models out of it. Not doing any kind of tracking, though.